# Como fazer cache de um bitmap no android?

Tags: android

Ola, estou fazendo um aplicativo pro meu tcc, no momento ele esta buscando uma lista de imagens no banco de dados e mostrando em uma listview no android, porem quando faço a transição de lista, ele faz busca de novo, isso faz com que o aplicativo fique muito pesado, então eu gostaria de fazer o cache do bitmap, assim quando abrir o app ele use as imagens que baixou.
Estou pegando um array de byte e tranformando em bitmap, isso dentro um baseAdapter e gostaria de saber como posso fazer o cache do mesmo.

```
public class UsuarioAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<Usuario> usrs;
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

public UsuarioAdapter(Context context, List<Usuario> usrs,
        ImageLoader mImageLoader) {
    this.usrs = usrs;
    this.context = context;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.mImageLoader = mImageLoader;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return usrs.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return usrs.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return usrs.get(arg0).getId();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        int layout = R.layout.lista_de_usuarios;
        view = inflater.inflate(layout, null);
        view.setTag(holder);

        holder.ivFoto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivLvFoto);
        holder.tvNome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvLvNome);
        holder.tvIdade = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvLvIdade);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    Usuario usr = usrs.get(position);

    holder.tvNome.setText(usr.getNome());
    holder.tvIdade.setText(usr.getIdade() + " Anos");

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(usr.getFoto(), 0,
            usr.getFoto().length);
    holder.ivFoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    return view;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView ivFoto;
    TextView tvNome;
    TextView tvIdade;
}
```

}

O bitmap que me refiro se encontra nessa linha do codigo :

```
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(usr.getFoto(), 0,
 usr.getFoto().length);
 holder.ivFoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: [Android Developers - Caching Bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html)

Answer (score 1):

Existem várias maneiras de se fazer isso no Android. Mas não fique reinventando a roda. Existem inúmeros frameworks prontos para fazer isso. Entre eles eu recomendo o

- Volley: (desenvolvido pelo próprio Google)
  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/
  Inclusive ele tem uma ImageView específica para fazer cache das imagens dispensando qualquer tipo de implementação extra (veja NetworkImageView).
- Picasso: Um dos mais utilizados é bem fácil de implementar e também poupa muito trabalho. https://github.com/square/picasso

Você consegue tutoriais de qualquer um destes com uma simples pesquisa no Google. Para não perder tempo eu utilizaria o Picasso que é muito simples, basta você utilizar o Gradle ou o Jar dele e com uma única linha você já consegue o que quer. Mas se você quer se especializar em dev Android eu recomendo profundamente estudar o Volley.

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo os seguintes links, onde possui exemplos de como trabalhar com cache de bitmaps:

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Espero ter ajudado.
Boa sorte.